# how to add space in button value on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if ($(e).is(':visible')) {
        $(e).attr("value", "      x      ");
    }
}
```

script.js

```
<ul class="nav nav-list panel-tabs filterButtons">
    <li>
        <input class="btn input-arya btn-primary"
               type="button" data-target="#decidedNo"
               data-toggle="tab" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="With Decided No">
        </input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

xxxx.html

I want to add spaces with the value. I can't.

output button value ;

```
"x"
```

Comment: Give padding boss! Even after your edit, **give padding in CSS**, not value!

Comment: but add the after space

Comment: Try with `$(e).attr("value", "         x         ");`

Answer (score 3):

OKay, so first few things:

1. There's no `</input>`, so close the tag in the starting tag.
2. Use `padding` in CSS and not `&nbsp;` for introducing spaces.
3. With `:visible` class, you can actually use the normal styles in CSS.

```css
input {padding: 0 15px;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list panel-tabs filterButtons">
  <li>
    <input class="btn input-arya btn-primary" type="button" data-target="#decidedNo" data-toggle="tab" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="With Decided No" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or with more space:

```css
input {padding: 0 75px;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list panel-tabs filterButtons">
  <li>
    <input class="btn input-arya btn-primary" type="button" data-target="#decidedNo" data-toggle="tab" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="With Decided No" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you asked for " "

Edit: you can use "\xa0" for javascript or String.fromCharCode(160), both are equal to space.

&nbsp is for html entities

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    if ($(e).is(':visible')) {
        $(e).attr("value", " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    if ($(e).is(':visible')) {
        e.value = "    "
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-list panel-tabs filterButtons">
    <li>
        <input class="btn input-arya btn-primary"
               type="button" data-target="#decidedNo"
               data-toggle="tab" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="With Decided No">
      
    </li>
</ul>
```